# Simplest way to display colored 3D boxes in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, opengl, 3d

For a project I want to display a 3D scene with boxes in a winform application. For each box I want to set the length/width/height x/y/z coordinates and the color.I want this to be as simple as possible, although the user should be able to rotate the scene with the mouse.

I've been doing a lot of googling, but all solutions that I find are way more complicated than I believe they need to be. Every example makes you draw every point and every vertice yourself.

The closest I've come to a simple solution is the SharpGL library with the scenecontrol. There you can simple code:

```cs
var cube = new Cube();
cube.Transformation.ScaleX = 0.3f;
cube.Transformation.ScaleY = 0.2f;
cube.Transformation.ScaleZ = 0.4f;
cube.Transformation.TranslateX = 1f;
cube.Transformation.TranslateX = 2f;
cube.Transformation.TranslateX = 3f;
sceneControl1.Scene.SceneContainer.AddChild(cube);
```

But I'm unable to find out how to add color and user controls. I found almost no documentation of this library.

Shouldn't there be a really simple library where you can just code something like:

```cs
Scene.AddBox(length, width, height, x, y, z, Rx, Ry, Rx, color)
```

Or am I missing something? I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: User control showing a [simple scene](https://imgur.com/j2aRjN8) using only native WPF components. The same user control can be used interchangeably in both WPF and Winforms apps. In Winforms an `ElementHost` is needed.

Answer (score 2):

You should use WPF/C# and get the AB4D library or Helix Toolkit.

AB4D costs money but it would be super easy to do this. I have used AB4D but not the Helix toolkit.

Check out Powertoys at: https://www.ab4d.com/powertoys.aspx

Comment: Oh geeze, punished for trying to answer a question that doesn't meet the "rules"

Comment: I think the Helix Toolkit will be the choice for me for this project. I'll just have to bite the bullet and switch to WPF (which isn't a bad idea anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Forget about using windows forms for this, it was meant for interfaces not 3D rendering, and it still does a poor job.

Comment: Could you recommend any other way to do this from c# (preferable embed it in a winform, but use some other type of control?)

Comment: I would use unity, if the interface isn't too complex. If it is then WPF with some libraries. The only reason to use Winforms now is if you have legacy code or your company works with that.

Answer (score 0):

Running OpenGL with winforms to render a cube seems hard to me but it's possible.

I suggest you use the web version of opengl. WebGL.

You'll need a browser. Problem is winforms has a bad web browser built in. So you'll need a more modern browser.

You got a few options:
Edge (EdgeHTML)
Chrome (Chromium)
Firefox (Gecko)

I had an experience with all of them in winforms. They all have some advantages and some drawbacks.

We'll go with Edge since this browser is built into Windows 10 and you can embedde it straight into your WinForms app by using the Windows Community Toolkit.

Please install the Windows Community Toolkit for WinForms NuGet package on your project.

Now refresh your toolbox and drag a WebView control to where ever you want the cube.

(Design size up to you ...)

Next step is writing some code.

You'll have to write a bit of JavaScript and HTML to get the cube on the screen.

Here's an example I found online: 
https://codepen.io/dbrandt/pen/mEbqZz

After you got your HTML right do something like this:

```
webView.NavigateToString(yourHtmlAsString);
```

And you got yourself a 3d cube rendering with opengl on Winforms !